Unable to share google form created through google forms api
I am in the process of creating a google form through the google form API.
These are the steps I have taken:

I created a project here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent?project={project name} with the google forms api activated

I have created a google form with the questions i would like to ask.


The issues begin here:

I am unable to see this google form in my forms location on my google account. The only way i can access it is by running the below code and clicking on the resulting url. Why can't i see the resulting google form on my google account?
form_metadata = form_service.forms().get(formId=FORM_ID).execute()
print(form_metadata)
print(form_metadata['formId'])
print(form_metadata['responderUri'])

I am able to fill out the google form I created but am not sure how to retrieve the answers to the form? When looking online its says i need to also connect to the google sheet associated with the form but i am unsure how to do that.


Just to review, i have created a google form that i can only access through a url in python and i do not know how to access the answers to the form.
This was my attempt at trying to retrieve the answers to the form but i dont think its particularly close:
# Import necessary libraries
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

# Define the scope and credentials
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'C:/python/nfl_poll_py/credentials.json' # Replace with the path to your credentials file

# Load the service account credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# Create a service object for the Google Sheets API
sheets_service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# Define the ID of the spreadsheet linked to your Google Form
SPREADSHEET_ID = 'your_spreadsheet_id'  # Replace with your Google Sheet ID
RANGE_NAME = 'Sheet1!A1:Z1000'  # Adjust the range to fit your needs

# Retrieve the response data from the Google Sheet
try:
    sheet = sheets_service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        # Convert the data to a DataFrame for easier manipulation
        df_responses = pd.DataFrame(values[1:], columns=values[0])
        print(df_responses)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred while fetching responses: {e}")

I've tried to see if there is a way to find the form on my google drive/google account but its not there. The code to create the form has work but i can't share it or get any data from it.

Answer to question 1:
Your question 1 is as follows.

I am unable to see this google form in my forms location on my google account. The only way i can access it is by running the below code and clicking on the resulting url. Why can't i see the resulting google form on my google account?

When I saw your showing script, the Google Form is created by the service account. The Google Drive of the service account is different from the Google Drive of your account. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, I guess that the following threads might be the answer.
google service account credentials not working
In this thread, I proposed the following patterns. You can choose one of them.

Share the file created by the service account with your Google account.
Create a folder in your Google Drive and share it with the email of the service account. And, the file is created in the shared folder.

Or, as another approach, if you are the account in the Google workspace and you want to use the service account to impersonate your account, please check domain-wide delegation.
Answer to question 2:
Your question 2 is as follows.

I am able to fill out the google form I created but am not sure how to retrieve the answers to the form? When looking online its says i need to also connect to the google sheet associated with the form but i am unsure how to do that.

If the Spreadsheet of SPREADSHEET_ID = 'your_spreadsheet_id' is put into the Google Drive of your Google account, please share the Spreadsheet with the email of the service account. By this, your script works.
If you want to directly retrieve the items in the Google Form, you can also the following script.
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account


SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'C:/python/nfl_poll_py/credentials.json' # Replace with the path to your credentials file

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.responses.readonly"]
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

form_id = "###" # Please set your Google Form ID.
service = build('forms', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
res = service.forms().responses().list(formId=form_id).execute()
print(res)

If you want to retrieve the Google Form in your Google Drive using the service account, please share it with the email of the service account.
References:

Related thread.

google service account credentials not working


[https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms.responses/list](Method: forms.responses.list)

